# How to loop through SQL data and draw a graph using ChartJS?

Tags: javascript, python, chart.js, bottle

This is a fraction of my data

```
| Firm       | Product     | Sales        |
|:-----------|------------:|:------------:|
| A          |        TV1  |     This     |
| A          |        TV2  |    column    |
| B          |        TV3  |     will     |
| C          |        TV4  |      be      |
| C          |        TV5  |    number    |
```

I would like to make a graph like this using ChartJS and bottle/Flask

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/WAz8U.jpg)

Code in bottle.py:

```
c.execute("SELECT DISTINCT Firm FROM database")
result1 = c.fetchall()
firms=[j[0] for j in result1]
c.execute("SELECT * FROM database")
database = c.fetchall()
```

Code in Javascript:

```
 data: {
    labels: [
        % for firm in firms:
        '{{ firm[0] }}',
        %end        
    ],
    datasets: [
        % for item in database:
        {
        label: '{{ item[1] }}',
            %if '{{ item[0] }}' == 'A':
                data: [{{ item[2] }},null,null],
                backgroundColor: "#0e7a0d"
            elif '{{ item[0] }}' == 'B':   
                data: [null,{{ item[2] }},null],
                backgroundColor: "##e4000f"
            else:
                data: [null,null ,{{ item[2] }}],
                backgroundColor: "#003791"
            %end 
        },
        %end 
    ]
```

But it only shows a empty canvas.

Edit: To get the result like this:

```
data: {
labels: ["A", "B", "C"],
datasets: [{
  label: 'TV1',
  backgroundColor: "rgba(153,255,51,1)",
  data: [10, 0, 0],
}, {
  label: 'TV2',
  backgroundColor: "rgba(255,153,0,1)",
  data: [0,30, 0],
  }]
 }
```

I should have my Js code like this:

```
        %if  item[0]  == 'A':
            data: [{{ item[2] }},null,null],
            backgroundColor: "#0e7a0d"
        elif  item[0]  == 'B':   
            data: [null,{{ item[2] }},null],
            backgroundColor: "##e4000f"
        else:
            data: [null,null ,{{ item[2] }}],
            backgroundColor: "#003791"
        %end
```

Comment: You can't have more than one key in a dictionary, and your code adds multiple 'data' elements.

Comment: @eatmeimadanish: I have added a working sample Js code. Would you mind helping me?

Comment: Can you make a SO code snippet that is working? use Ctrl -M. I tried your code and got "Error: {
  "message": "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 15,
  "colno": 9
}"

Comment: here is the result I want [link]( https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yGxLLX)